# Drawing curved midarrows in diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have trouble drawing this diagram in tikz, could anybody help me?
[image: Text]

Answer (score 2):

Most likely completely wrong physics-wise but with *bent* arrows.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{% 
    attach arrow/.style={
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length}/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}%
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-3*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-1*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1+\tmpArrowTime/2} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length},bend]}] plot[smooth]
         coordinates {(@1) (@2) (@3) (@4)};},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     },
     attach arrow/.default=0.5,
     arc arrow/.cd,length/.initial=2mm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[bend]},thick,y=0.5mm,
    dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.2pt},
    declare function={y1=5;y2=74;y3=139;y4=85;x1=1;x2=5;}]
 \draw[->] (6,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,150) node[above]{$[{}^\circ\mathrm{C}]$};
 \draw[attach arrow] (x2,y1) coordinate[dot] (p1) to[out=170,in=-60] 
 (x1,y2) coordinate[dot] (p2);
 \draw[attach arrow] (x1,y3) coordinate[dot] (p3) to[out=0,in=130] 
 (x2,y4) coordinate[dot] (p4);
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  {\draw[dashed] (p\X) -- (0,y\X)
  node[left]{$\pgfmathparse{y\X}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$};}
 \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 3] in {A,B} 
 {\draw[dashed] (p\Y) -- (p\Y|-0,0) node[below] {$\X$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]